# Having an Asynchronous method inside a try catch with recursion will work as expected?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, recursion, try-catch

This is the code where I initialize my custom logger, the way it works is I instanciate the class frmLog in the MainForm, and this, which is the frmlog instanciate the logger. The logger is nothing fancy, it works with a queue from the server, which I copy while I lock it, and then i dump the queue into a txt. What failed was the process of the queue, but I dont want to take any chances.

**What I expect to happen with this code is**: Every time there is a problem in the logger which makes it throw an exception which is not handled, to catch it here and restart it. Would this work as intended?

```
    Server Server;
    LogHelper logger;
    int counter = 0;
    public frmLog(Server server)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Server = server;

    }


    void inicializarlog()
    {
        logger = new LogHelper(rtbLog, Server, this);

    }

    private void btnSalirLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void frmLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainAsync();
    }

    private async Task MainAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => inicializarlog());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fallo el asincronico: " + ex.Message);
            if(counter++ >= 5)
               MainAsync();
            else
               Console.WriteLine("Fatal error, shutting down the logger");
        }
    }
```

Edit: The retry and the polly library its if the work fails, since what im doing is creating an instance of a logger, it will always finish, the problem is after the fact. unless i got a problem in the server

Comment: Why won't you run it and see?

Comment: Async void methods have different error-handling semantics, this might be similar to what you're asking https://stackoverflow.com/a/50617278/2946329

Comment: @Guy i did run it, and by now i didnt found any issues, but with the code before i havent had any issues in a long time. And After 6 hours of running it failed. Thats why im asking someone more experienced in the matter of async

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retries in Catch block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062867/retries-in-catch-block)

Comment: How high is the probability that when it fails once, it will fail "forever" ? Or at least very very often in a row?

Comment: @nalnpir consider using a library that already has a [retry functionality](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry), such as [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) - see [Implementing the retry pattern in c sharp using Polly](https://alastaircrabtree.com/implementing-the-retry-pattern-using-polly/)

Comment: @S.Akbari i read that, but i think it doesnt apply in this particular case, since im using a delegate method so im basically putting it into a context. But im not sure to be honest

Comment: @RuiJarimba It isnt the same kind of retry rui, since it ends the execusion and continues. So if i implement it like that it wouldnt do me any good. I ll check the Polly

Comment: @Fildor the problem is not that the probability is low or high. It is unacceptable that the server crashes due to not being able to log

Comment: Yes, it is a problem. It if constantly fails, your server will never get out of that retry-loop. And using recursion, you'll end up in Stack Overflow (pun intended).

Comment: @Fildor good one :-)

Comment: @Fildor I see your point, i will put a maximum number of retries

Comment: 2 Questions: Does this _really_ need to be async? 2nd: If so, why did you not make it "async all the way"? I.e. `private async void frmLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await MainAsync();
    }`

Comment: Reason I think it shouldn't be async: You may end up with the situation that logger is used before it is set up.

Comment: @Fildor the logger cant ever be used before its set up, since my knowledge when i programmed this was very little on how to make it work, my idea was to set up a queue in the server consumed by the logger. So it cant never be used before setting up. And what difference would it make to use the await MainAsync?